# Open source, non-GPL SID emulator

Tags: commodore-64, emulation, licensing, mos-6581

I am looking for a SID emulator that is open source, but not GPL. In particular, I am looking for something with a license that allows me to link it to a closed-source program; and also one that allows me to take its source code and rewrite it in a different language targeting a different platform, and then release that rewrite under an open source license. LGPL, or MIT/BSD would be examples of licenses that would work for me.

I know of the following SID emulator engines, but all of them are GPL:

- [TinySID](https://github.com/robn/tinysid)
- [FastSID](http://vice-emu.sourceforge.net/)
- [SIDPlay](http://sidplay2.sourceforge.net/)
- [jsSID](https://github.com/jhohertz/jsSID), source rewrite of the above three

Then there's also

- [cSID](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=153597)/[cSID-light](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=156587): source seems to be gone, can't find licensing info

Comment: You could always wrap it in a GPL server which communicates via an open API to your closed source program.

Comment: Another idea is to ask the programmers if they would re-license it (for a grant) for you.

Comment: @Arne: that's a can of worms. See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#AggregateContainers , in particular: _But if the semantics of the communication are intimate enough, exchanging complex internal data structures, that too could be a basis to consider the two parts as combined into a larger program._ **TLDR:** Licensing issues are complex.

Comment: I like Janka's idea, for the record. A lot of authors pick the GPL by default for protection while being able to enjoy seeing their code be useful — I'm sure at least one would be happy to relicense to you with a suitable guarantee of credit and references to the GPL original.

Comment: GPL does allow you to rewrite it in a different language for a different platform, as long as the rewrite is released under the same license.

Comment: @immibis right, sure, but I need something that allows me to do both things.

Comment: I assume you mean software only and not hardware?  If hardware, I was going to recommend the SIDCog using a Parallax Propeller micro-controller that has almost perfect SID emulation (up to 6-7 of them on ONE chip).

Comment: @Tommy: You are assuming that each GPL-licensed SID emulator has a single author. But it is very common for free software programs to have multiple authors (sometimes simply because one author incorporated code from another without his or her knowledge).  If the OP wanted a special licence for such a program, he or she would need to obtain the consent of _all_ the authors.

Comment: @Psychonaut that is a substantial flaw in my "at least one" logic; a SID emulator isn't that big of a project (purely in terms of amount of code needed to express a solution; I mean to imply nothing as to research and effort) so it is separately likely that some single-author solutions exist but that's kind of a separate argument. My first does indeed have the flaw you identify.

Comment: @ninjalj Just write a CC0-licensed library with the same API but a stub implementation and link to that. The user dropping in the original library would get the same result, but that's how linking works. GPL people have fought hard to assert that interface isn't copyrightable, but want to then assert interface is copyrightable; Nintendo faced a similar attempt in a lawsuit, and won after a none-too-happy judge wrote a scathing opinion about the plaintiff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One open source, non-GPL SID emulator that I have found is another one also called jsSID, but completely independent of the one linked in the original question. This one is available from http://hermit.uw.hu/index.php (latest [download link](http://hermit.uw.hu/software/jsSID-0.9.1-tech_comments.zip)) and contains the following license in its `README.txt`:

> Licenses? The license is the popular WTF license, so 'do what the fukk you want with this code'. :)
>    I'd be grateful if my name/credits won't be removed from it, but otherwise feel free to use it as you wish.

The emulator is written in JavaScript and includes its own 6510 emulator as well.

Comment: There is also a cSID C++ version. But sadly without source code.

Answer (score 0):

[`sid-arduino-lib`](https://github.com/cybernesto/sid-arduino-lib) is <strike>L</strike>GPL. Its downside is that it is written targeting AVR microcontrollers, so porting it to a desktop setting would be more involved.

Comment: Christoph Haberer's [original](http://www.roboterclub-freiburg.de/atmega_sound/atmegaSID.html) is GPL, not LGPL, so the author claiming their work is LGPL may be a violation of the original licence